# What is the generated $\sigma$-Algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

What is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the following system of sets:

$X=\mathbb{R} , \mathbb{G}=\{A\subset X| |A|=2\}$?

How can I solve such problems? I suppose that the generated algebra cannot ave more than 2 elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{C} = \{A \subseteq X: A \text{ is countable or } A^c \text{ is countable} \}$. Then $\sigma(\mathbb{G}) = \mathcal{C}$.

*Proof.* Verify that $\mathcal{C}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. If $|A|=2$, then clearly $A \in \mathcal{C}$. Therefore, $\sigma(\mathbb{G}) \subseteq \mathcal{C}$ (why?). Conversely, suppose $A \in \mathcal{C}$. Verify that $\sigma(\mathbb{G})$ contains all singletons $\{ x\}$, $x \in X$. If $A$ is countable, it is a countable union of singletons, and hence in $\sigma(\mathbb{G})$. On the other hand if $A^c$ is countable, then the same reasoning shows that $A^c \in \sigma(\mathbb{G})$, hence $A \in \sigma(\mathbb{G})$. Therefore, $\mathcal{C} \subseteq \sigma(\mathbb{G})$, and we're done.